# Where should I put price calculation logic in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In this question I am asking for "best practice" advice for Laravel. 
I am working on an "airbnb-like" website where I list accommodations.
On various pages in the site (backend and frontend) I need to calculate the price for the accommodations. The price is calculated by combining the accommodation object with the search query. 
Eg. 
-accommodation: rate = 50 euro per night 
-search query: 4 nights 
-> result: total price = 200 euro 

Where should I put the logic that makes these price calculation? 
 For example:

-Should I create a PricesController for this? 
-Should I add functions/methods to the AccommodationsController that calculate this, or to the Accommodation model?
-Should I create a ServiceProvider for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no defined way to pull this off, which in my opinion is the greatest thing about laravel.

Maybe create a directory named `Calculations` in `app/` (`app/Caclulations/Accommodation.php`), and namespace it as such? It would be an nice object oriented approach to this problem.

```
namespace App\Calculations;

class Accommodation
{
    /**
     * The rate per night.
     *
     * @var float
     */
    protected $rate;

    /**
     * The amount of nights for the stay.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $nights = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param float $rate
     * @param int   $nights
     */
    public function __construct($rate = 50.00, $nights = 1)
    {
        $this->rate = $rate;
        $this->nights = $nights;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the accommodation and returns the result.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function calculate()
    {
        return $this->rate * $this->nights;
    }
}
```

This way you can modify the calculation class if the calculation changes, extend it from other calculations (such as a base calculation), and maybe insert some other useful things in the class such as currency type.

Usage:

```
$total = (new Accommodation($rate, $nights))->calculate();
```

Comment: Hi Steve, That seems like a good solution. I have created a class for the price calculation which accepts an instance of Accommodation and and instance of the search query. I bind this class to the app and call it like this
```$bookData = App::make('PriceCalc', [$accommodation, $searchData])```.
Then all methods are available to me like this
```$bookData->totalPrice()``` etc. Does that seem good to you?

Comment: Hi @SiteHopper, that seems fine, but in my opinion there isn't really a need to bind the class to the app itself and call the `App::make()` method on the calculation class. If you know the class and the arguments it needs to construct it, then you might as well create the instance yourself using `$bookData = new PriceCalc($accomodation, $searchData);`. But in the end it's all up to you! :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Im a bit confused about the usage of binding a class to the app. When would this be appropriate?

Comment: **In my opinion**, binding objects to the Application itself should be reserved for site wide services that need to be used frequently, such as Session, Cache, Database, FileSystem, etc. These are objects that are hard / resource intensive to instantiate at a later time during the life-cycle of the request. Instead of depending on the entire `App` facade, you can just depend on the `PriceCalc` class and create the instance when you need it, since binding it to the application would cause it to be instantiated on every single request. I hope I'm explaining myself clearly, please let me know! :)

Answer (score 1):

Realistically speaking you are wanting this logic in more than one controller. Due to this there is no point in repeating this logic in multiple controllers.

I would create a service provider. With this, you can then use `dependancy injection` to utilise this logic where ever you require. By having this logic in a single place you allow for easier maintenance & an easier life.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to get. If you think it's the one-time calculation, i.e; you don't have to use this calculation outside this method, it's ok to go with it. Otherwise, if you think you will have to use this calculation logic outside/in other controllers/classes then you can write this a file as a method, or can create a helper class holding your method. It's up to you.